# Need to understand link between Job and Position on Oracle 12.2.9 HRMS

Tags: oracle

I need to understand how and jobs and positions are linked in R12.2.9. I have a requirement to create a new Job but link it to an existing position or vice versa.
Is it possible. If so, how to do it via an API.

I have created a Job like TESTJOBPOS1 using the API below:

```
hr_job_api.create_job
```

Then while trying to create a position and Job mapping using below API:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  lv_position_name            VARCHAR2(500);
  ld_effective_start_date     DATE;
  ld_effective_end_date       DATE;
  ln_position_definition_id   NUMBER;
  ln_object_version_number    NUMBER;
  ln_position_id              NUMBER;
BEGIN
  lv_position_name          := 'APOS_TEST5'; -- Existing Position
  ld_effective_start_date   := NULL;
  ld_effective_end_date     := NULL;
  ln_position_definition_id := NULL;
  ln_object_version_number  := NULL;
  ln_position_id            := NULL;
  
  hr_position_api.create_position
     ( p_validate                 => FALSE,
       p_job_id                   => 3335, -- Job id
       p_organization_id          => 0, -- Business Group id
       p_date_effective           => '01-JAN-1990',
       p_segment1                 => 'APOS_TEST5', 
      -- p_segment2                 => 'POSITIONN',
       p_status                   => 'VALID',
       p_position_id              => ln_position_id,
       p_object_version_number    => ln_object_version_number,
       p_position_definition_id   => ln_position_definition_id,
       p_name                     => lv_position_name
     );
                                  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ln_position_id);                                  
END;
```

I am getting this error:
ORA-20001: A position with this name already exists. Enter a new name.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: details of the problem (i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` tables for some sample data in your database); the existing code you are using; the issues/errors with your existing code; and the expected output. If this is not related to an Oracle Database then do not use the [Oracle] tag.

Comment: hi @MT0, added the relevant details now.

Comment: You are using `HR_POSITION_API.CREATE_POSITION` to try to create a position that already exists and the database is (unsurprisingly) giving you an error that the position already exists. What do you expect to happen? Why not just use the name of the position that you know already exists and assign the job to that position using the appropriate API for doing that?

Comment: You are right @MT0. I know that I am trying to create the same position again. My understanding is that the job and position combo is unique and hence Oracle should allow me to create a new job - (old) position combination. How can I assign the new job to an existing position. I am unable to find any API for that. 
I know for a fact that Fusion HCM allows that and I want to implement similarly in R12.